# Can you use Order of Scribes: Manifest Mind feature to prevent counterspell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, counterspelling

Pretty straightforward question: as per feature's description, I can cast a spell as if I were in the place of my Awakened spellbook. So, using this feature, and being 60 feet from enemy spellcaster, I cannot be targeted by counterspell, if Awakened spellbook is outside of range of counterspell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Your specific example doesn't prevent a *counterspell*

The relevant text of the [Mainfest Mind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#OrderofScribes) feature is (emphasis added):

> Whenever you cast a wizard spell on your turn, you can **cast it as if you were in the spectral mind’s space, instead of your own**, using its senses.

This means that for all intents and purposes, the spell is cast from the mind's space and *not* from your space. At first glance this seems like what you want. However, *you* still occupy only your space, and unfortunately for you, the trigger for [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell)'s reaction is:

> when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell

So if you are within 60 feet of the enemy mage and you are casting a spell, that makes you a valid target for *counterspell*, even though the spell is being cast from another space further away.

### Manifest Mind does enable *some* anti-counter shenanigans

While your idea doesn't work, there are several ways to exploit the Manifest Mind to cast a spell while denying any possible *counterspell*. The trick is to get the spectral mind in a position to cast the spell at the enemy while keeping yourself out of range or out of the enemy's line of effect. Here's a couple of examples:

If you have a spell with a 30 foot range that you would like to cast on the enemy mage, simply manifest the mind within 30 feet of the enemy while keeping *yourself* more than 60 feet away, and then cast the spell from the mind's space. Since you are out of *counterspell* range, the enemy cannot attempt to counter the spell, but they will be in range of your spell's effect when you cast it from the mind's space.

Similarly, if you can get behind full cover, you can send your manifest mind out of cover to allow you to target the enemy with your spell while preventing them from countering it, since they don't have line of effect to *you* through your cover.

Answer (score 2):

#### *Counterspell* targets the other caster, so Manifest Mind should not prevent it from working.

The *Sage Advice Compendium* contains an official ruling on the function of *counterspell*:

> [**Does *counterspell* target the caster or the spell you’re trying to counter?**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA269)
>
> *Counterspell* targets the other spellcaster.

Even when casting a spell through Manifest Mind, the caster is still within range of *counterspell* performing the spellcasting components of the spell. So even though for the purposes of the spell effect the spell is considered to be cast at the location of the Awakened Spellbook, *counterspell* targets the caster who is still within the range of *counterspell*.